Hide element in Object mode?
I'm trying to do snapping in Object Mode, but the model has a lot of vertices that are close to each other (very dense). I have trouble picking the correct vertex as a snap reference. I thought about hiding the complex elements in Edit Mode, but when I go back to Object Mode, the hidden parts show up again. Is it possible to hide elements in Edit Mode and keep them hidden when returning to Object Mode? The only solution I have right now is to zoom in really close to pick the vertex.

Does displaying the wireframe in Object mode help?

it's already in wireframe, but without zooming really close, I can't tell which vertex it's snapping.

In Edit Mode, select the vertices you want to hide, press Ctrl+G > Assign to New Group, then in Object Mode, add a Mask Modifier targeting the group.
Click on the double blue arrow icon to switch between "Show group only" and "Hide Group".
A simpler way to snap is to use Shift+S > Cursor to Selected and then Shift+S  > Selection to Cursor.

